# What is this large tree with long leaves and no smell?

Tags: identification, trees, leaves

Could you please help me identify this plant?
 It looks like a wild tree on some vacant land I visited.
This tree has lanceolate leaves, and is about 6-8 meters tall.
I did not see any flowers at that time, and it's odorless. It has a lush canopy and a hard leaf texture.
I live in Indonesia and I found this tree on Java Island.

[image: it has a lush canopy]
[image: hard leaf texture]

Thank you so much for your attention
Firgita

Comment: Hi Firgita, the picture isn't very accurate. Does this tree has any particularity that would help us identify it? e.g. smell, flower, anything else?

Comment: Another photo from further away that shows growth habit/overall shape would be useful

Comment: Welcome Firgita! Where did you see this tree? Is that where you live? How big is the whole tree? Whatever details you can add will help us try to identify it. We might end up putting it on hold until we get more information. If so, that's explained on [this page](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in our [help].  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be many possibilities not excluded by any details in the Q (I have already suggested a laurel as a possibility) but, appearing to me to tick what boxes are available: *Syzygium*, maybe [*Syzygium cumini*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium_cumini) ("Java plum").

Comment: i thought it same too..its kinda like syzygium families. Well, thank you so much